# to_char function is giving syntax error

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, to-char

In the below query, I have used strftime function to get the date in string format. It worked fine in sqlite database. But when the database is changed to progress it threw an error that "SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function strftime(unknown, timestamp without time zone) does not exist"

The below code worked in SQLite and threw an error in Postgres database

```
public function testArchiveSidebar()
{
    $archives = Question::query()->selectRaw('strftime(? ,created_at)as year,
        strftime(?,created_at) as month,count(id) as qcount' ,['%Y','%m'])
        -> groupBy('year','month')
        ->orderByDesc('created_at')
        ->get();
    $this->assertTrue($archives->count()>0);
}
```

So, I used the to_char function instead of strftime. However, it is throwing the error.

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: YYYY (SQL: select to_char(created_at ,YYYY) year, to_char(created_at ,Mon) month from "questions" group by "year", "month" order by "created_at" desc)

Query using to_char

```
public function testArchiveSidebar()
    {
        $archives = Question::query()->selectRaw('to_char(created_at ,YYYY) year,
                    to_char(created_at ,Mon) month,count(id) as qcount')
            -> groupBy('year','month')
            ->orderByDesc('created_at')
            ->get();
        $this->assertTrue($archives->count()>0);
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass literal:

```
to_char(created_at, YYYY)     -- before
=>
to_char(created_at, 'YYYY')   -- after
to_char(created_at ,'Mon')
```

Comment: Lukasz: Thanks for your response. If I understood correctly you suggested removing the quotes right? If I do so, it is giving me a syntax error in Laravel

Comment: @JyostnaUmmadisetty I am suggesting surround it with `'`

Comment: @JyostnaUmmadisetty: no, Lukasz suggested to **add** the single quotes, because Strings are enclosed in single quotes in SQL

Answer (score 0):

The second argument `to_char` takes is a string - you need to surround it with quotes:

```
$archives = Question::query()->selectRaw("to_char(created_at, 'YYYY') year,
                to_char(created_at, 'Mon') month, count(id) as qcount")
```

Comment: Mureinik: Thank you for your response. I tried the same but still getting the below error - Caused by
**_PDOException: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "year"
LINE 1: select to_char(created_at, 'YYYY') year,_**

Comment: I guess the error is due to that I didn't add AS before year and month. I have added, but getting the error **_Caused by
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR:  column "questions.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function_**

Comment: Can you pls help me with the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's working with the below query. Thanks to all for providing your insights.

```
 $archives = Question::query()->selectRaw("to_char(created_at, 'YYYY') as year,
                to_char(created_at, 'MM') as month,count(id) as qcount")
            -> groupBy('year','month')
            ->orderByRaw('min(created_at) desc')
            ->get();
```